# Convert Single Byte from byte array to string using UTF-8

Tags: java, arrays, utf-8

I need to convert Each byte b from byte array to string using UTF-8 .I am able to convert entire byte array to string using UTF-8.Please help.Below is my code that have buffer which is byte array.

```
String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8"); 
// convert the array of bytes to characters using the default encoding.                   
Log.d("es.pymasde.blueterm",str);                     
// for each byte in the buffer(byte array)
for(byte b:buffer)
{
  //Here I need to convert Each Byte b to string using UTF-8                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Exmaple may help you

```
public class TestByte
{    
        public static void main(String[] argv) { 
        String example = "This is an example";
        byte[] bytes = example.getBytes(); 
        System.out.println("Text : " + example);
        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString()); 
        String s = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
     }
}
```

Output

Text : This is an example

Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca

Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca

Text Decryted : This is an example

Comment: I found it on net.But it didnt helped me because I need to decode byte using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast each byte to `char`.

```
    for (byte b : buffer) {
        // Here I need to convert Each Byte b to string using UTF-8
        System.out.println((char) b);
    }
```